# AndroidStudio: MediaPlayer не проигрывает аудиофайлы до конца

Tags: android, аудио, mediaplayer, recycleview

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при нажатии на элемент recycleview должен проигрываться аудиофайл (прописано в адаптере). Аудиофайл проигрывается, но не до конца. Грешу на поток, который обновляет данные в RecycleView. Как такое можно решить:

**Сам поток**

Thread t=new Thread(){

```
@Override
public void run(){
    while(!isInterrupted()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);  //1000ms = 1 sec
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                            //асинктаск, получающий данные с сервера и загоняющий их в RecycleView
                            getMessages gm = new getMessages();
                            gm.execute();
                        }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

};

**Код адаптера**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    String randname;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<OneMessage> phones;

    MessageAdapter(Context context, List<OneMessage> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_messages, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
             OneMessage phone = phones.get(position);
        if(phone!=null){
            final OneMessage mobila=phone;
            holder.textpartview.setText(phone.getText());
            holder.textpartview.setBackgroundColor(phone.getCol());
            holder.textpartview.setTextColor(phone.getTextcol());
            holder.lin.setBackgroundColor(phone.getCol());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mobila.voice!="nil"){
                        Log.i("EST","KONTAKT");
                         randname = genRandString();
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/STTM/RecordedAudio/"+randname+".wav");
                        byte[] snd = Base64.decode(mobila.voice,1);
                        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                            fos.write(snd);
                               } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        JThread jh = new JThread();
                        jh.execute();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return phones.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView textpartview;
        final LinearLayout lin;
        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textpartview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            lin=view.findViewById(R.id.lin);
        }
    }
    class JThread extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/STTM/RecordedAudio/"+randname+".wav");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();

            return null;
        }
    }

    public String genRandString(){
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(20);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();
return output;

    }
```

Пользователь получает массив элементов класса "сообщение", одним из параметров которого является голос("voice") в формате Base64. При нажатии на элемент RV происходит проверка, есть ли в этом элементе голосовое сообщение. Если есть, то переводим его из формата Base64 в .wav и проигрываем.

Как можно решить такую проблему? Пытался до этого пытался делать проверку по txt файлу: если в нём 1, то обновляем, если 12 - не обновляем, однако всегда была единица, даже когда "на практике" там было 12. Заранее спасибо за вашу помощи!

Answer (score -1):

Чтож, ларчик просто открывался. Асинхронный поток удалял файл быстрее, чем он проигрывался, отчего файл физически не мог быть проигран до конца. Решается всё очень просто: удаление файла нужно поместить не в onPostExecute, а в setOnCompletionListener. Вот таким стал код асинктаскового проигрывателя

```
 class JThread extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/STTM/RecordedAudio/"+randname+".wav");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    st=0;
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/STTM/RecordedAudio/biba.wav");
                    if(file.exists()) file.delete();
                }
            });
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();


            return null;
        }
    }
```

Надеюсь, это решение будет кому-нибудь полезным.

Comment: Интересно то, что вряд-ли вам кто-нибудь смог помочь, так как в вопросе не было ни слово про удаление после проигрывания, ни полного кода asynctask